# How to reassign a boost shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have two Boost shared_ptr's

```
shared_ptr<X> A(new X);
shared_ptr<X> B(new X);
```

And a 3rd pointer that initially points to the same X as A.

```
shared_ptr<X> C = A;
```

What is the correct way to change C such that it points to the same X as B?

```
C = B;
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Is something not working? Looks fine.

Comment: If you're just looking for confirmation, yes, `C = B;` is correct.

Comment: Yep, that'll work, why not try it??

Comment: `C.reset(new X);` or `C = A` if `A` is a `shared_ptr<X>`

Answer (score 2):

EdChm is right. I have made a small test programm to explicit it.
It uses C++ 11 but can be transposed easily.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<int> A(new int(1));//creates a shared pointer pointing to an int. So he underlying int is referenced only once
  std::shared_ptr<int> B(new int(2));//creates another shared pointer pointing to another int (nothing to do with the first one so the underlying int is only referenced once
  std::shared_ptr<int> C;//creating a shared pointer pointing to nothing

  std::cout<<"Number of references for A "<< A.use_count()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"A points to "<<*(A.get())<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Number of references for B "<< B.use_count()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"A points to "<<*(B.get())<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Number of references for C "<< C.use_count()<<std::endl;

  std::cout<<"Now we assign A to C"<<std::endl;
  C=A; // now two shared_ptr point to the same object
  std::cout<<"Number of references for A "<< A.use_count()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"A points to "<<*(A.get())<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Number of references for C "<< C.use_count()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"C points to "<<*(C.get())<<std::endl;

  std::cout<<"Number of references for B "<< B.use_count()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"B points to "<<*(B.get())<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

the example is largely inspired from this link.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/

Hope that helps,
Feel free to ask for more details.